# When Installing ShareKit 2.0 all Products are red and cannot subclass DefaultSHKConfigurator

Tags: ios, xcode, sharekit

I have followed the instructions for downloading Share Kit and setting it up from https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit . I am doing the manual download and have downloaded all the submodules and put them in their directories.

WHen I get to step 3: Smoke test it all builds fine but the products are all still red
[image: the products]

I have then tried starting the configuration but as soon as i create a subclass of DefaultSHKConfigurator i am told that it cant find the DefaultSHKConfigurator.h file [image: subclass]

Comment: Product are red, because they do not exist yet.

Either you do not have the files on right places, or you omitted some sub steps in step 2.

Wonder why have you not used git commands? It is much easier than downloading...

Comment: I have not used git commands as the project I am working on is not a git project nor can it be changed to one. I have gone through each of the steps three time now to ensure i have not missed anything

Comment: You can create a git repo temporarily, download files and then remove .git directory. Make sure you have correct header search path.